# iOS: What is the callback when tapped on the empty space between keyboard and search bar to dismiss the keyboard when search bar is active

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have `SearchController` for my `TableViewController`. I wanted to perform some actions when user taps on the empty space on the screen (between the keyboard and search bar) to dismisses the keyboard and displays the main Table View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `-searchBarTextDidEndEditing:` in `UISearchBarDelegate`?